# How to create landscape and portrait modes using core graphics?

Tags: objective-c, ios9, core-graphics, landscape-portrait

I have an app that I created quite a while ago, on an iPad in Portrait mode; my users are now asking for Landscape mode also.  My problem is that two of the pages are created using core graphics (CGRect etc) to draw the lines (horizontal and vertical) which work.  This is an image of the first page:

[image]

My question is: how do I make this landscape and portrait in one app using constraints, or is there another way of doing it (hopefully easier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any easy way. If you create the objects here programatically, you could supply a "factor" of x and y to the whole thing.

For example, if you create a calendar rect = `(w,h)` in portrait, then you could change that to `(w * xFactor, h * yFactor)`. Then you change/adjust the xFactor and yFactor in the orientationChange delegate and redraw.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I have to determine the orientation and then apply the "factor" to each drawing component accordingly... correct?

Comment: Yup. I don't see your code so I can't really comment more. No idea how you created those objects by "CoreGraphics". Normally we should just subclass a UIView and create the objects. But still, without applying constraints, you need to manually adjust the sizes/position by code.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "just subclass a UIVIew and create the objects"?  I don't see how using that would expand and contract depending on the mode (landscape or portrait), unless you are referring to one UIView for each mode?

Comment: Subclass uiview would make your job easier to resize. Because all the subviews in it will just reposition/resize themselves if you use autoresizing. better if u use constraints in them. then you just need to iterate all the subclassed objects and apply width/height. if you draw objects manually by coregraphics it seems you going to need to redraw and resize everything including those inside the objects.

Comment: OK... let me throw one more caviat at you... if you notice the image I posted above, each of the "squares" in the actual calendar must be accessible, i.e. I need to know what day the user tapped.  In addition to that, I also need to know what row and column (time and staff name) the user tapped on the lower half of the screen.  Is this possible with subclassing as you suggested in your last comment, or am I biting off more than I can chew? (I'm not an expert by any means on the deep tricks of coding for iOS).

Comment: Yes, subclassing allows that (actually that is the purpose of subclass- so you can add custom properties/behaviours to your objects). Anyway i think we're offtopic here.

Comment: @SpokaneDude, if you're interested, I made a simple subclass to illustrate what I mean here: http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.my/2016/12/how-to-create-custom-objects-in-ios-apps.html